# How can I use peg revisions in Perl SVN::Client

Tags: perl, api, svn, svn-api

The Perl bindings for Subversion in SVN::Client (I'm looking at [Michael Schwern's version in CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.6.12.1/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm), but I don't think it's significantly different from the version at Apache), mention peg revisions only in the context of the 'info' method.

Is there a way to specify a peg revision on a 'checkout' or 'update'?

I've tried appending '@84779' to the url, but that gives me error 160013 ('Filesystem has no item: \'...(url).../trunk@84779\' path not found'). But if I give the same URL + peg to the command-line client it works, so I am guessing that the peg revision is interpreted in the client CLI code. But how does it pass it on?

Comment: Please use version agnostic links unless you need to point at a specific version. i.e. use one of http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SVN::Client https://metacpan.org/module/SVN::Client http://p3rl.org/SVN::Client .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Removed unhelpful information about the standard documented methods taking `$revision`. Apologies.

Turns out SVN::Client is full of undocumented methods that wrap the SWIG bindings. Looks like you may be after `SVN::Client::checkout2` which adds `$peg_revision` as an accepted parameter between `$path` and `$revision`. It doesn't look like the similar `update2` method handles peg revisions though.

Comment: Is that the regular revision though or [the peg revision](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html)?

Comment: Yes. They take a revision parameter. But I need to specify a peg revision, since the current creation of the specified resource doesn't go back to the specified revision. Please don't answer questions if you don't know enough about them to understand them.

Comment: You're right, and I apologise. I've edited my answer with information that will hopefully be a little more helpful.

Comment: You're right, so I've removed the downvote and accepted. I'd actually found that myself in the meantime. Actually the current version is checkout3, which adds further arguments. On reflection, I wouldn't expect it for 'update', because if you're changing the peg revision that's a switch. How I handle that case in my code is another question ...